# Remove related item in entity framework CF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to remove an item from database,

This item is related to other items.
when i try to remove it like this.

```
using (var ctx = new UmeaKommunFacilityContext())
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                ctx.Facility.Attach(oldFacilitiesToDelete[i]);
                                ctx.Facility.Remove(oldFacilitiesToDelete[i]);
                                ctx.SaveChanges();
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            { 

                            }
                        }
```

then i'm getting

```
An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker
```

i added this code to detach the item

```
ctx.Entry(oldFacilitiesToDelete[i]).State = EntityState.Detached;
                        ctx.Facility.Attach(oldFacilitiesToDelete[i]);
                        ctx.Facility.Remove(oldFacilitiesToDelete[i]);
                        ctx.SaveChanges();
```

then i got the same exception.

then what to do to be able to remove the item from db.
this item type (Facility) is related to other types, and i have removed all aother related by this code and it worked

```
  using (var db2 = new UmeaKommunFacilityContext())
                {
                    try
                    {

                        Facility f = oldFacilitiesToDelete[i];
                        List<Image> images = f.Images.ToList<Image>();
                        for (int j = 0; j < images.Count; j++)
                        {
                            db.Images.Attach(images[i]);
                            db.Images.Remove(images[i]);
                            db.Entry(images[i]).State = EntityState.Detached;

                        }


                        List<Material> materials = f.Materials;
                        for (int j = 0; j < materials.Count; j++)
                        {
                            db.Materials.Attach(materials[i]);
                            db.Materials.Remove(materials[i]);
                            db.Entry(materials[i]).State = EntityState.Detached;

                        }


                        List<Polygon> polygons = f.Polygons;
                        for (int j = 0; j < polygons.Count; j++)
                        {
                            db.Polygons.Attach(polygons[i]);
                            db.Polygons.Remove(polygons[i]);
                            db.Entry(polygons[i]).State = EntityState.Detached;
                        }


                        db.SaveChanges();

                    }
                    catch (EntityException ex)
                    {
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {  }

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing `Attach()` and `Remove()` on the same item?

To remove an item from database you need to use the Delete action. For example:

```
ctx.Entry(oldFacilitiesToDelete[i]).State = EntityState.Deleted;
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

When you "Detach" an item you're simply removing it from the context, not from the database. That why you can always reverse with "Attach".

If the point here is to remove the related entity for an items, it's easier to implement .OnCascadeDelete(true) so you can remove only the main entity; EF will remove the other related items for you, like this:

```
        HasRequired(t => t.MainEntity)
          .WithMany(t => t.SubEntity)
          .HasForeignKey(d => d.MainEntityId)
          .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Comment: how to use OnCascadeDelete ?

Comment: I updated my answer with a simple relationship you can use as example.